# Some confusion with Linq-to-Objects query operating on results of Linq-to-Entities query

Tags: linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

Linq to objects expression returns an object, which when enumerated yields elements from the sequence. Normally, deferred LINQ-to-Object  methods act as a pipeline, thus each element of the sequence flows through the processing pipeline before the next element is processed.

a) But if Linq-to-Objects query operates on results of a Linq-to-Entities query, then when  `foreach` tries to iterate `search`, does again each element flow through the whole processing sequence before next element is processed (in other words is first element from the sequence retrieved from the DB, then processed by `Enumerable.Where`, then by `Enumerable.SelectMany` and only then is next element retrieved from the DB) or is the entire set of elements retrieved from the DB at once (when `foreach` tries to read the first element from the sequence), and only then do these elements start flowing through the processing pipeline of Linq-to-Objects operators?

```
        var search = context.Contacts.AsEnumerable().
            Where(s => s.ContactID > 10).SelectMany(s => s.Address);
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `context.Contacts` is processed by the EF query provider which translates expressions (from `IQueryable`) into SQL.

Then, by `AsEnumerable`, the link with the EF query provider is broken and anything after that is linq to objects, working on the result set from the preceding statement.

However, since `Contact.Address` is a lazy loaded collection, for each `Contact` that passes the pipeline a new query is emitted to populate it. This is possible because EF uses a proxy type for `Contact` that overrides `Address` by a getter that runs a query through the EF query provider.

As you probably know, when you erase `AsEnumerable` the whole statement turns into an `Expression` tree that EF will translate into one SQL statement.

Comment: 1)So the entire set is retrieved form DB at once and only then do Enumerable operators begin processing elements? 2)Is it correct that even with this query Enumerable operators will start processing particular element only when all Enumerable operators finished processing the preceding element?

Comment: The db query runs and after `AsEnumerable` any chain of linq statements is evaluated as one pipeline. It must be clear though that the whole statement (including db part) is only executed when it is actually enumerated.

Comment: May I ask what you mean with "as one pipeline"?

Comment: Without intermediate result sets. The result set is created in one enumeration in linq to objects.

Comment: "Without intermediate result sets. The result set is created in one enumeration in linq to objects" Meaning Enumerable operators evaluate the input elements in the same way as when an input sequence is not IQueryable (of course first the entire set is retrieved from the DB)?